# Как изменить предыдущее сообщение в телеграмм боте

Tags: python, aiogram-3.x

Всем привет, есть простенький код бота, суть проста, при каждом новом callback новое сообщение редактируется на старое. Когда мы переходим к функции empty_func у нас есть возможность выбрать другой тип пароля, т.е после того, как пользователь нажмет на эту кнопку, мы должны переводить его на начальную функцию command_info. Функция another_password_type отрабатывает, но она выводит новое сообщение, а хотелось бы, чтобы она просто меняла предыдущее сообщение. Я думаю это происходит по причине того, что функция another_password_type(callback) пытается вызвать функцию, которая имеет аргумент message. Я так понимаю callback дружит только с callback?
Все остальные функции отрабатывают как нужно.

```
@dp.message(Command('info'))
async def command_info(message: Message) -> None:
    builder = InlineKeyboardBuilder()
    button_1 = InlineKeyboardButton(text='Слабый пароль', callback_data='weak_1')
    button_2 = InlineKeyboardButton(text='Средний пароль', callback_data='average')
    button_3 = InlineKeyboardButton(text='Сложный', callback_data='diff')
    builder.add(button_1, button_2, button_3)
    builder.adjust(2)
    text = 'Выбери какой пароль необходимо сгенерировать'
    await message.answer(text=text, reply_markup=builder.as_markup())


@dp.callback_query(Text('weak_1'))
async def empty_func(callback: CallbackQuery) -> None:
    builder = InlineKeyboardBuilder()
    button_1 = InlineKeyboardButton(text='Тыкни', callback_data='click')
    button_2 = InlineKeyboardButton(text='Изменить тип пароля', callback_data='another')
    builder.add(button_1, button_2)
    text = 'Хоп, сообщение поменялось'
    await callback.message.edit_text(text=text, reply_markup=builder.as_markup())


@dp.callback_query(Text('average'))
async def empty_func_2(callback: CallbackQuery) -> None:
    builder = InlineKeyboardBuilder()
    button_1 = InlineKeyboardButton(text='Тыкни_2', callback_data='click_2')
    builder.add(button_1)
    text = 'Хоп, сообщение поменялось_2'
    await callback.message.edit_text(text=text, reply_markup=builder.as_markup())


@dp.callback_query(Text('click_2'))
async def click_2(callback: CallbackQuery) -> None:
    await empty_func(callback)


@dp.callback_query(Text('another'))
async def another_password_type(callback: CallbackQuery) -> None:
    await command_info(callback.message)
```

[image: Сообщение "Выбери какой..." должно быть в "Хоп, сообщение..."]

Answer (score 0):

Можно передать аргумент message в функцию another_password_type и затем передать его в command_info, чтобы обойти эту проблему.

```
async def another_password_type(callback: CallbackQuery, message: Message) -> None:
    builder = InlineKeyboardBuilder()
    button_1 = InlineKeyboardButton(text='Тыкни', callback_data='click')
    button_2 = InlineKeyboardButton(text='Изменить тип пароля', callback_data='another')
    builder.add(button_1, button_2)
    text = 'Хоп, сообщение поменялось'
    await callback.message.edit_text(text=text, reply_markup=builder.as_markup())
    await command_info(message)

@dp.callback_query(Text('weak_1'))
async def empty_func(callback: CallbackQuery) -> None:
    builder = InlineKeyboardBuilder()
    button_1 = InlineKeyboardButton(text='Тыкни', callback_data='click')
    button_2 = InlineKeyboardButton(text='Изменить тип пароля', callback_data='another')
    builder.add(button_1, button_2)
    text = 'Хоп, сообщение поменялось'
    await callback.message.edit_text(text=text, reply_markup=builder.as_markup())

@dp.callback_query(Text('another'))
async def change_password_type(callback: CallbackQuery) -> None:
    message = callback.message
    await another_password_type(callback, message)
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ, возможно, я не совсем корректно поставил свой вопрос. Необходимо именно сделать вызов command_info, чтобы она отработала ровно также, как и click_2. Мы в click_2 не делаем callback.message.edit_text, мы просто вызываем empty_func, при этом у нас empty_func появляется в том же сообщении. Именно так нужно мне сделать с another_password_type. Пока не особо понимаю, как это возможно.